# In swift how do I get the screen size and what is it measured in?

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, screen-size

I been trying to or a SKLableNode on top of my screen but if I put the screen size in the y it's off? I noticed the middle of the screen is always the same for every iPhone I use. I also noticed I took the top point of the screen and the bottom point and subtract them and didn't get what the screen height was telling me. Please Help and thank you.

Comment: If you want to get the size of the screen including the status bar, use `UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds`. It is measured in points. The "scale" of the screen (i.e. is it @1x, @2x, @3x) is accessed by `UIScreen.mainScreen().scale`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using SpriteKit I would go in to the GameScene.sks file and make sure the scene orientations are right. Portrait or landscape, whatever you want for your game. 
You can also use `self.frame.height` for y and `self.frame.width` for x position. If you want to be in the middle of the screen you could just say `self.frame.height/2`. Screen sizes are measured in pixels and are of type CGFloat. I'm not sure if this was really what you were asking for but it could help you.

Comment: How do I change the GameScene.sks file and what do I do it. I tried to change the rectangle around but I know how or understand it.

Comment: To change the gamescene you look on the right sidebar and change the height and width.

Answer (score 0):

i hope this helps you..

```
var screenwidth : CGFloat!
var screenheight : CGFloat!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    screenwidth = self.view.frame.size.width
    screenheight = self.view.frame.size.height
    println("\(screenwidth) ,\(screenheight)")
}
```

Comment: It may return the wrong frame in viewDidLoad due to Autolayout.